# ASP.NET Core 2 Web API, Azure publish issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0

I have created a sample Web API that returns some sample data from an SQLite database which is included in the project.

I am able to browse and run the API on my local computer. This is all good.

I am also able to publish that API on Azure, all files are getting deployed I am getting "Publish successful" message as expected.

After, whenever I try to browse the azurewebsites.net domain, it doesn't browse it at all.

Once I create empty web site/web app, I am able to browse the welcome page on azurewebsites.net. But once I publish the API, I am getting 404 not found error, 503 error or IIS 502.5 error.

I tried to change settings from Azure portal, all settings seems good, .NET framework version is set to 4.7, as well as my project is too. Anyone has any idea?

**I found the problem**

I was using SQLite DB, and my SQLite database was open in a database editor. So, Even though Visual Studio published the database, the database file was 0 byte since it was in use and locked.

I think this is short of a bug. If Visual Studio says I published it successfully, I believe it. Obviously it wasn't successful at all. I reported this as a bug to the VS team.

So, making sure non of your files are in use is a good idea to check.

Comment: have you tried hitting the web api on azure with a REST client like Postman?

Comment: I did try it, it throws internal error. I am using SQLite, would that be the problem? Because if I exclude SQLite from my project, API works well. But once I put SQLite in it, it gets into trouble.